# Share openvpn connection on the interface connected to internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, route, connection-sharing

I have Linux VM in my local network, with OpenVPN perfectly working on it. Let's say my main gateway (router, actually) is `192.168.1.1`, VM ip is `192.168.1.15`. That's my VM network settings on the interface connected to the Internet:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

`route -n` output before start of OpenVPN:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.60.165.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And after start of OpenVPN:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      10.80.165.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 game
10.60.0.0       10.80.165.1     255.252.0.0     UG    0      0        0 game
10.60.165.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.80.0.0       10.80.165.1     255.252.0.0     UG    0      0        0 game
10.80.165.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 game
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

From other machines I need to connect to ip `10.80.156.1` through VM. So, I set the gateway on other machine to ip of VM. I can access Internet this way, but address `10.80.156.1` is unreachable.

UPD: `iptables -L -n` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Show your iptables rules on VM.

Comment: @IporSircer, see updated answer

Comment: I meant all tables. Especially `nat`. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can reach internet from any machine which use 192.168.1.15 as default gateway. You have to nat the connection:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: That worked! I found my mistake. Haven't considered rebooting the machine resets iptables rules